# Microsoft _stprintf warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf

Why I get the following warning for the following code :)

Code:

```
_stprintf(m_szFileNamePath,_T("%s"),strFileName);
```

> warning C4996: '_swprintf': swprintf has been changed to conform with the ISO C standard, adding an extra character count parameter. To use traditional Microsoft swprintf, set _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS.

I know _strprintf is a macro which if _UNICODE is defined will evaluate to _swprintf else it will be sprintf.

Now what is this _swprintf. There is a function swprintf, but why is _stprintf evaluating to _swprintf instead of swprintf.

What is the difference b/w the _xxx and xxx functions?

**EDIT:**

Okay there are two definitions for the UNICODE version of _stprintf, which one is included?

The one in tchar.h or strsafe.h?

Comment: Are you asking about _stprintf or _strprintf, or what? Please edit your question to be consistent.

Comment: i am asking about _stprintf, that was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28VS.80%29.aspx

> swprintf is a wide-character version of sprintf; the pointer arguments to swprintf are wide-character strings. Detection of encoding errors in swprintf may differ from that in sprintf. swprintf and fwprintf behave identically except that swprintf writes output to a string rather than to a destination of type FILE, and swprintf requires the count parameter to specify the maximum number of characters to be written. The versions of these functions with the _l suffix are identical except that they use the locale parameter passed in instead of the current thread locale.
>
> In Visual C++ 2005, swprintf conforms to the ISO C Standard, which requires the second parameter, count, of type size_t. To force the old nonstandard behavior, define _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS. In a future version, the old behavior may be removed, so code should be changed to use the new conformant behavior.

Comment: Why is it giving the warning then?

Comment: Doesn't the warning explain that? Because they have changed the behavior. People generally like to know when code doesn't do what they expect. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
_stprintf(m_szFileNamePath, 256, _T("%s"), strFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides its own extension of CRT _swprintf - is not compatible (for example) with unix

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft (used to?) prefix otherwise widely available non-win32 functions that were not part of the C standard with underscore.

Comment: Okay there are two definitions for the UNICODE version of _stprintf, which one is included????

The one in tchar.h or strsafe.h?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
int len = swprintf( buf, 100, L"%s", L"Hello world" );
```